# Dynamical allocation of 2D-array

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, dynamic-memory-allocation

Can someone tell me the description of this code snippet please?

```
chessBoard = new char*[ tRows ] ;
for ( unsigned int c = 0; c < rows; c++ )
{
    chessBoard[ c ] = new char[ columns ];
}
```

**Questions:**

What is `char*[tRows]` and what would be its effect?
And, what is `chessBoard[c]`?

Please give me the precise description.

Comment: Why not `char (*chessboard)[tRows] = new char[tRows][tRows];` and forget the loop and allocating for each row. Then when done, `delete[] (chessboard);` Which provides the benefit of a single allocation and single free.

Comment: Relevant (C++11): https://stackoverflow.com/a/16239446/7670262

Answer (score 0):

```
char *chessBoard  = new char[ tRows ] ; //correct definition
//chessBoard is a pointer to array of tRow size of characters

for( unsigned int c = 0 ;   c < rows ;   c++ )
chessBoard[ c ] = new char[ columns ] ;
//we assign each row with a constant number of columns
```

As you already know a chessboard can be basically represented as a ***square matrix*** hence

```
Matrix dimension: Row x Column where Row = Column
```

Hope that answers your question!

Cheers,

Arul Verman

Answer (score 0):

While you are free to declare and allocate for a *array of pointers to char [tRows]* and then loop allocating for each row, you can also declare a *pointer to array of char [tRows]* and allocate `tRows` of them in a single call which provides the benefit of a single allocation and single free, e.g.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

#define tRows 10

int main (void) {

    char (*chessboard)[tRows] = new char[tRows][tRows];

    for (int i = 0; i < tRows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < tRows; j++) {
            chessboard[i][j] = i + j;
            std::cout << " " << std::setw(2) << (int)chessboard[i][j];
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
    }

    delete[] (chessboard);
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/newdelete2d
  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11
  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12
  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13
  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14
  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15
  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16
  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17
  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18
```

and, confirming your memory use:

```
$ valgrind ./bin/newdelete2d
==7838== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==7838== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==7838== Using Valgrind-3.12.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==7838== Command: ./bin/newdelete2d
==7838==
  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11
  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12
  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13
  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14
  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15
  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16
  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17
  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18
==7838==
==7838== HEAP SUMMARY:
==7838==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==7838==   total heap usage: 2 allocs, 2 frees, 72,804 bytes allocated
==7838==
==7838== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==7838==
==7838== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==7838== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```